# Is it possible to successfully adjust predictive text for offensive words?

Tags: sms, keyboard, dictionary, text-prediction

I am using a oneplus 5t, and Gboard. I use signal to text.

I have cleared the personal dictionary within gboard, and I have also enabled "do not make offensive suggestions" in the keyboard options. I don't believe signal has an associated settings option.

Still.. for some reason when I type 'sucking', I get 2/3 followup suggestions that are predictably offensive.

I would just rather not see words like this, and I can guarantee I've never used this particular combination of words before, so I don't understand why this is happening.

Either the "offensive predictive text" function is broken, or these words are not considered to be part of that dictionary (I find this hard to believe). Or something else entirely...

Comment: Are the suggested words offensive words (you wouldn't mind never seeing those words again in any context) or are they only offensive in this context?

Comment: @Lazer you are correct and I hadn't considered that part - I am referring here to Richard (Dick) Tracy and a Rooster (cock).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can dis-associate the word from the phrase by deleting it as a suggestion. As per [Get word suggestions & fix mistakes](https://support.google.com/gboard/answer/7068415?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en):

> Get word suggestions & fix mistakes
>
> 1. On your Android phone or tablet, install Gboard.
> 2. Open any app that you can type with, like Gmail or Keep.
> 3. Tap where you can enter text.
> 4. Type a word. At the top of the keyboard, you’ll see suggestions:
>
>    - If you see the word you want, tap it.
>    - **If you don’t like a suggested word, touch and hold it, and then drag the word to Trash.**

I tried it out and I don't get the test word I moved to trash as a suggestion for the one that I dis-associated it from, but I still get it as a suggestion after other words.

Comment: This is the correct answer and was much simpler than I had imagined - and for some reason did not turn up in my own searching. Works perfectly.